# Why is the IR transmitter tied to one pin

Tags: infrared

I'm using IRremote.h  (https://github.com/Arduino-IRremote/Arduino-IRremote).  The receiver allows you to change the pin it is connected to but the transmitter does not.  Is there any reason why this is hardcoded in IRremoteInt.h.  If it just a PWM pin, can't any PWM pin be used?

```
#if defined(CORE_OC2B_PIN)
#define TIMER_PWM_PIN        CORE_OC2B_PIN  /* Teensy */
#elif defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
#define TIMER_PWM_PIN        9  /* Arduino Mega */
#elif defined(__AVR_ATmega644P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega644__)
#define TIMER_PWM_PIN        14 /* Sanguino */
#else
#define TIMER_PWM_PIN        3  /* Arduino Duemilanove, Diecimila, LilyPad, etc */
#endif
```

There is not much documentation on this.

Comment: have you tried using another pin?

Comment: Where are those pin definitions? Just have found some pin numbers in IRTimer.hpp. Though by default you can use any pin for sending since the timing is done via software. The pin definitions come only to play when you want to use a hardware timer in PWM mode. Then you can provide the corresponding defines to tell the library which Timer to use. Thats important,  since it will directly access the corresponding registers of that Timer

Comment: So in short, I need to modify the header and source if I wish to use any pin for sending.  No idea why the author designed the receiver to take any pin but not the sender.  I'll just change it to accept any pin and send the mods to the author.

Comment: @cup I would guess the author did it that way because thats the way most Arduino libraries are.  "There is not much documentation on this" adds weight to that assumption.  IMO a lot of libraries are generated because the author needs the functionality and then they are published because the authors are just nice people and are willing to share.  In this case the author probably never thought about using a different pin, the wire was connected to port 9 why would 'he' need it on port 8.

Comment: @cup ... There is also the chance that there is a hardware restriction that was in force at the time that meant it could only be on port 9, it was the only port that supported PWM? Maybe now the limitation is no longer there.
But anyway you have the right idea, if you can improve a library do so and feed it back into the repo.

Comment: I'll do the changes, test it and then feed it back to the author.  Can someone close this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to the bottom of it.  As mentioned in the comments, this is tied to the timers.  The list is given in [Secrets of Arduino PWM](https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/generic/secrets-of-arduino-pwm).  The code can be changed to use a different timer but it will still be tied to a specific pin.